# XMPP using OpenFire in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

How can we use XMPP and Openfire to send files to another iOS devices which are on different networks.

I have developed the source code that is working on same network to send the files but the same code is not working to send the files to different network.

Let me know if you have any solutions for these issues.

Comment: did you find any solution ?